# C# How to build a datatable from a single column of a datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

Most questions want to do the opposite of what I'm trying to do. I'd like to build a datatable from a single column of an existing datagridview. There are some questions here that try to do this with another datatable or datacolumns, but I would like to do it directly from my datagridview.

Also I would prefer if there was a more efficient way than to loop through all the column's rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   //Copy Data
}
```

copying the data one by one, since I might have large numbers of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)(dataGridView.DataSource);
```

And then remove the columns you do not need with `dataGridView.Columns.Remove()`.
That should be the most efficient way.

Comment: Unfortunately my datagridviews datasource is a bindingsource, and so I get a cast exception.